# Pass kwargs to function argument explictly

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Is there a way in Python to pass explicitly a dictionary to the `**kwargs` argument of a function? The signature that I'm using is:

```py
def f(*, a=1, **kwargs): pass # same question with def f(a=1, **kwargs)
```

I tried to call it the following ways:

```py
my_dict=dict(b=2)
f(kwargs=my_dict) # wrong, kwargs receives {'kwargs': {'b': 2}} instead of {'b': 2}
f(**kwargs=my_dict) # SyntaxError: invalid syntax
f(kwargs=**my_dict) # SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The reason I want to do this is that the dictionary I pass in may contain the key `a`, and I don't want it to pollute the `f`'s argument `a`:

```py
overlap_dict=dict(a=3,b=4)
f(**overlap_dict) # wrong, 'a' is 3, and 'kwargs' only contains 'b' key
f(a=2, **overlap_dict) # TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'
```

Replacing `**kwargs` with a dictionary in `f`'s signature is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change `f` to accept more parameters, you could simply make `a` take a list and the first entry is for `f`, and the second entry is for `kwargs`, for instance:

```py
def f(*, a, **kwargs):
    if len(a) == 1:
        a = a[0]
    elif len(a) == 2:
        kwargs['a'] = a[1]
        a = a[0]
```

You can also do something similar with a dictionary:

```py
def f(*, a, **kwargs):
    if 'kwargs' in a.keys():
        kwargs['a'] = a['kwargs']
    a = a['f']
```

Alternatively, this does change `f`'s parameter inputs, but I think it's a bit clearer. There are 2 cases I can think of. First, if you know that `a` will always be set in `kwargs`:

```py
def f(*, a, a2, **kwargs):
    kwargs['a'] = a2
```

The other case is if you want it to be optional whether `a` passes to `kwargs`:

```py
def f(*, a, a2=None, pass_a=False, **kwargs):
    if pass_a:
        kwargs['a'] = a2
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the `kwargs` with `a` and then pass it. Example, say you have a value `a=1`, then do like this.

```
kwargs["a"] = a
f(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Unfotunately, this doesn't seem to fix either of the two usecases I presented (see code after "the reason I want to do this". Please don't hesitate to provide a more described solution for these cases if it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily (or permanently, if you want – just remove the last line) modify `f` to take `kwargs` as a keyword argument. Note that this is a somewhat evil hack, so I would urge you to try other workarounds first.

```py
import inspect


def f(*, a=1, **kwargs):
    print(a)
    print(kwargs)


code = f.__code__
f.__code__ = code.replace(
    co_kwonlyargcount=code.co_kwonlyargcount + 1,
    co_flags=code.co_flags - inspect.CO_VARKEYWORDS,
)
f(kwargs={"a": 3, "b": 4})
f.__code__ = code
```

This prints:

```py
1
{'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```

Comment: This is an interesting comment, but it does not solve my issue because it's too hacky in my opinion, and it's still sidestepping my constraint to keep the signature of `f` (statically *and* dynamically).

Comment: @Codoscope In that case, I believe the answer is: ‘it’s impossible’.